# Partially Ordered Set that is NOT a lattice?

Tags: examples-counterexamples, order-theory, lattice-orders

So, I'm looking at partially ordered sets and lattices and I can find a ton of examples of sets that are lattices, but I cannot find any examples of a partially ordered set that is NOT a lattice. What would be an example of a partially ordered set that is not a lattice?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)#Counter-examples

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/742817/if-a-finite-poset-has-greatest-and-least-elements-is-it-a-lattice

Comment: Please *do search* before asking. This particular question was not at all difficult to find. A simple search of "poset not lattice" would have provided the above mentioned link.

Answer (score 2):

For a trivial example, take a two-element set $\{a,b\}$ with $a\not\le b$
and $b\not\le a$.